# VSTS find workitems between two releases

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, tfs-query

To compare the related work items between the current release and a previous release I can use the following:

[image: Associated workitems]

Is there possible to create a query to get the same work items between two releases? Or alternatively the VSTS Rest API.

My reason for this is to create a list of Features > Stories > Tasks to fill the release notes. Using the above UI makes it pretty time intensive to find out the relation between the tasks and features.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Retrieve work items by calling

```
https://{account}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/[teamproject]/_apis/Release/releases/{current release id}/workitems?api-version=4.1-preview.1&baseReleaseId={compare release id}
```

It just return the id, url of work items, you need to get details of work item through [Get a list of work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#by-ids) REST API.