# VSTS Release API Documentation

Tags: azure-devops

In the following post uses the VSTS release API to get all the work items associated with a release: [VSTS find workitems between two releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48909858/vsts-find-workitems-between-two-releases)

It uses the following call:

```html
https://{account}.vsrm.visualstudio.com/[teamproject]/_apis/Release/releases/{current release id}/workitems?api-version=4.1-preview.1&baseReleaseId={compare release id}
```

workitems isn't listed in the VSTS API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/releases/get%20release?view=vsts-rest-4.1

Is there a more complete list available that I simply can't find? Is it possible to get the list of commits similar to:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the REST APIs are documented here : [Visual Studio Team Services REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1)

However some related REST APIs are not documented. For these REST APIs we can use tools such as [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or directly press <kbd>F12</kbd> - `network` in Chrome to track them.

Based on my test, no such a REST API can directly retrieve the compared commits from Release. Actually the different commits are retrieved by several REST APIs, get information from corresponding changesets then compare them...

So, if you want to get the different commits with REST API, you need to retrieve the changeset ID from previous release and the changeset ID in current release. then compare them.

e.g:

```
POST : https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_api/_versioncontrol/history?api-version=5.0-preview.1

Request Body:

{"repositoryId":"","searchCriteria":"{\"itemPaths\":[\"$/0522TFVCScrum/PS\"],\"fromVersion\":\"180\",\"toVersion\":\"183\",\"top\":50}"}
```

[image]